# VSCode: editor.background, per user, per workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often work on multiple projects with multiple instances of VSCode open simultaneously. It would be nice to have a different background color in each instance so I can differentiate them easily.

I can add:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "editor.background": "#xxxxxxx"
 }
```

in my user settings, but then it changes the background color for all instances of VSCode. Or, I can add that to the workspace settings. Unfortunately the workspace setting file is under source code control (for other workspace-relevant settings), so that changes it for everyone else on my team, annoying them.

Is there a way to configure a per-user, per-workspace setting, or perhaps an extension?

Comment: In the .vscode folder in your project root you can put a settings.json file with your colorCustomizations that will affect only that workspace.

Comment: Yes this is an old thread, but I found myself in the same position. I've manage to differentiate my vs code instances by using [peacock extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) . Yes it writes to the settings file, but if your colleagues don't have the extension installed, it won't change anything for them (maybe a warning for invalid setting params, when they open the settings 'menu')

Answer (score 11):

From [workspace and user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

> VS Code provides two different scopes for settings:
>
> **User** These settings apply globally to any instance of VS Code you open
>
> **Workspace** These settings are stored inside your workspace in a .vscode
>   folder and only apply when the workspace is opened. Settings defined
>   on this scope override the user scope.

So in your root folder for each workspace within a .vscode folder you can add a settings.json with

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.

{

  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editor.background": "#f00"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that you can put that in the workspace settings. But, since that file is under source code control, that background color applies to everyone else on the team. I'm asking for a way to set the background color per user, per workspace.

Comment: This answer is correct and I'm using it now and it's awesome. As for source code control, just add it to git ignore :-)